# Inserting element at the end of an array in c++ without using vectors

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ so my current code might be completely wrong.
I'm trying to get two inputs into two arrays I've declared two arrays of max size 10 and I want to use the console input and add it to the end of each array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   
char playerName[10];
char playerScore[10];
char name, score;

cout << "Enter the player name:";
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter the player score"
cin >> score;

for (i=0; i<10, i++)
{   
   // add name at the end of playerName
   // add score at the end of playerScore

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` is a just single character, probably not what you'd want for a name.

Comment: why "without using vectors" ? And why not `std::string` ?

Comment: If you want to work with arrays of chars instead of the more convenient options, then look in to stuff like https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat and also be sure you initialize your arrays properly and also leave room for the null terminator and also be sure the array is big enough for what you want to store...

Comment: *I've declared two arrays of max size `10`* - No. You declared two arrays of size `10`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use `string` not `char` if you want multiple characters. You also need to initialize `i` first.

Then you can add inputs at the end of your array like this;

```
int main() {
   
string playerName[10];
int playerScore[10];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {   
        cout << "Enter the player name: ";
        cin >> playerName[i];
        cout << "Enter the player score: ";
        cin >> playerScore[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to fill the whole array I just want to ask to input one element

Comment: An array of `std::string` is likely not what OP wants based on the text of their question. Specifically "I'm trying to get two inputs into two arrays [...]." Same with the `playerScore`. But it's hard to say. If they actually want an array of strings and matching scores, two disparate arrays is also not the way to go.

Comment: @HaifaBesrour You have already "filled" the array, with uninitialized values, simply by declaring it to have length 10. You cannot have an array that does not have elements.

Comment: @sweenish the end goal is an array of player names with its corresponding array of score for each player I wanted to create two functions one for adding player and their score two the corresponding arrays and the second is to remove a player from that array w

Comment: @HaifaBesrour This means that your original code and question are way off base. I would create a class to keep the relevent information together, and then you'd only need one array of that class type. And take advantage of what C++ has to offer. Your restriction seems odd, unless it's imposed by a professor.

Answer (score 0):

1- you must use `using namespace std;` after `#include <iostream>`
2- you must use `;` at the end of `cout << "Enter the player score"`
3- you must specify the type of i when you use for loop and use `;` between each part -> `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`
and for fill the character array use -> `cin >> playerName;` and `cin >> playerScore;`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n = 2;
    char playerName[10];
    char playerScore[10];
    char name, score;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the player name: ";
        cin >> playerName;
        cout << "Enter the player score: ";
        cin >> playerScore;
        cout << playerName <<'\n';
        cout << playerScore << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it is better to use a string

Comment: This works but when I try to do it twice and then print the array it only shows me the element that I recently inserted

Comment: @HaifaBesrour Yes, because `playerName` is not an array of names and `playerScore` is not an array of scores. They are both arrays of `char`, which `cin` and `cout` will treat as two C-style strings. When you do a 2nd `cin` into `playerName` and `playerScore`, the contents of the two strings are _replaced_ by the new string values you enter. Additionally, neither string can contain more than nine characters (plus the terminating nul character) and if you type more than nine characters your program will almost certainly do something bad.

Comment: if you want run several times , you can change the (n):
look at the code again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use character arrays, they should be 2d arrays, such as `char playername [10][10]`.

*Maximum name of 10 characters.*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    char playerName[10][10];
    int playerScore[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the "<<i+1<<"th "<< "player's name:";
        cin >> playerName[i];
        cout << "Enter the " <<i+1<<"th "<< "player's score:";
        cin >>playerScore[i];
        cout << "_________________________________________\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```